# How to connect Android with PC and run CMD commands

Tags: android, windows, cmd, controls

I've seen a few apps around that can run CMD commands from your android phone, but these require an program installed on your pc.
Is there any way to do this without a seperate program installed?

So you can just simply connect your phone and run a cmd command?

I'm looking for the next result:
Run the app > Enter local ip of target(pc) > Enter a cmd command to run on the pc.

Edit: Will be using WIFI connection for now, easy to setup and connect to any other internal ip.

Answer (score 0):

how should that work without any software on targe pc? With such "software" you can control all the pc's of the world...